# Searching/filtering by the date a contact was added to a group

Tags: groups, search, dates

When viewing a contact's Group tab, you can see the groups as well as the date that they were added to the group.

[image: Contact > Groups tab]

I've been trying to find a way to search based on the date that a contact was added to a standard group but running stuck. For example, a search for:

- contacts that are added to the "Newsletter Subscribers" group
- only those added within the last month

Is this type of thing possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have a [report for this on Github](https://github.com/MegaphoneJon/org.cpehn.subscriptionhistory).

EDIT: Ignore comments below; this report works on modern versions of CiviCRM, and Laryn's improvements are now part of my extension.

Comment: Thanks! I've been using this (forked with some tweaks) and it's doing what I need. https://github.com/laryn/org.cpehn.subscriptionhistory

Comment: Hooray for open source!  Happy to accept a PR with your changes, too.  I might even submit this to the extension directory since other folks are finding it helpful.

Comment:  PR submitted -- see what you think of the changes. :)

Comment: @JonG-MegaphoneTech – count me as someone who would be really grateful if you added "search by group add date" to the extension directory. :-)

Comment: @Eiljah you can download my extension from Github, or better yet Laryn's fork.  If you're constrained to the extension directory for whatever reason, the GDPR extension has a very similar report.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this in SearchKit by using the Contact Subscription Histories entity.